Getting error when trying to update: No Release File
I am trying to update my stretch release of Debian which is now in archive status and am getting the following error:

The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.

How can I get past this error?

Debian Stretch reached its end of long-term support on June 30th 2022. If you go the URL, you'll see that there is nothing there for Stretch: https://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/
You can add the Extended LTS repo with the instructions from here: https://www.freexian.com/lts/extended/docs/how-to-use-extended-lts/
For the important parts:
Manually install the freexian-archive-keyring:
wget https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/pool/main/f/freexian-archive-keyring/freexian-archive-keyring_2022.06.08_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i freexian-archive-keyring_2022.06.08_all.deb

Manually fetch the key:
sudo wget https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/archive-key.gpg -O elts-archive-key.gpg && sudo mv elts-archive-key.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/freexian-archive-extended-lts.gpg

Add the following to the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extended-lts.list
deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts stretch-lts main contrib non-free

Keep in mind that the repo only contains security updates. For all of the packages, add the following instead.
deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts stretch main contrib non-free

Afterwards
apt update

The recommend action here is to move to a supported release of Debian that has not reached EOL. Bullseye will reach EOL for security updates this June but Bookworm won't until June 26th. You'll run into things like this when running an EOL release of any operating system.
